# Intercept an ABase class while a Child class implementing the base class namely A and an independent interface namely IC is used in binding

Tags: ninject, ninject-extensions, ninject.web.mvc, ninject-interception

Intercept an ABase class while a Child class implementing the base class
namely A and an independent interface namely IC is used in binding.

```
Bind<IC>().To<A>();
```

Problem rises when I have a property in A which will be set to null in
proxified object, while in the Instance of the proxified object has
the right value for that prop in debug view .

```
((Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Wrapper.StandardWrapper)
  (((DistributorServiceProxy)(distributorService)).__interceptor)).Instance
```

To be exact I add the link to a gist https://gist.github.com/424637484504b89789d6
containing the actual code.

I will be very grateful if anyone can help me.

Cheers,
Jani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Just need the Repository property to be `public`, that's it;